# How to set array size in return by array input in Solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

How in solidity to set the fixed length of returned  array, according to the array in parameters?

```
 // For example I have this simple function, which convert array uint to int 

 // but this not works, because dynamic length array
 function convertUintToInt(uint[] _input) public pure returns(int[] _output){
     for(uint i = 0; i < _input.length; i++){
         _output[i] = int(_input[i]);
     }

    return _output;
  }



 // this works for length 10, but if input.length < 10 this return unnecessary empty items
 // if _input.length > 10 this will not works
 function convertUintToInt(uint[] _input) public pure returns(int[10] _output)



 // I need just something like this 
 function convertUintToInt(uint[] _input) public pure returns(int[_input.length] _output)
```

Main goal not use storage!

I just need create readable contract helper for convert data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;

contract Ballot {
    function convertUintToInt(uint256[] memory _input) public pure returns(int[] memory){
    int[] memory tmpArr = new int[](_input.length);
     for(uint i = 0; i < _input.length; i++){
         tmpArr[i] = int(_input[i]);
     }

    return tmpArr;
  }
}
```